# How to read data from 3.5mm jack on Raspberry Pi 2 with python or java?

Tags: java, python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I have a drone that has  a goPro and Video transmitter attached to it. the transmitter can transmit via wireless or through 3.5mm. How can i pick up this data through 3.5mm/composite video on a pi? the drone is a DJI phantom 2 and an iOSD transmitter. i want to use the transmitter video rather than the GoPro directly since the transmitter also applies a nice HUD to the video with flight specs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The composite video phono socket is an output device.